# How can I import my excel file to php myadmin without converting it to csv format

Tags: mysql, excel, phpmyadmin

How can I import my excel file to php myadmin without converting it to csv format, considering the excel file is too large.

Comment: What do you mean by symmetric data?

Comment: ignore the word symmetric..i have re-edited the question. thankyou.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

got my answer...and it worked perfectly.

answer-  http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/php-import-excel-file-into-mysql-database-tutorialexample.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.